# Need to run a VBA Macro on data refresh in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to prompt a macro to run on a data refresh. I have the macro that needs to be run build, but I am having an issue with the new values not being used since the macros embedded in the sheet are called using ActiveX ComboBoxs.

I am finding several instances where people refer to AfterRefresh and BeforeRefresh, but I think I am misunderstanding how this would take effect and call a macro.

I currently am running ComboBoxs so I have multiple instances of

```
Private Sub ComboBox22_Change()
'do stuff
End Sub.
```

but I need the 'do stuff' to occur upon a data refresh, including refreshes that happen automatically and upon sheet open.

I don't want to tie the refresh to a specific box because the items that are refreshed are not dependent on any one instance of data change.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a worksheet change event would help in this situation.

Right Click the sheet tab, select "View Code", Select "Worksheet" then "Change."

Code will automatically kick in when a specific range of cells has been changed.

[image: Right Click Sheet Tab]
[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub    ' this stops code error if more than one cell is changed at once

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:C10")) Is Nothing Then    ' indicates the Target range
        MsgBox "You have changed " & Target.Address & " to " & Target
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Lyndon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031310) had the following remark on your answer: *"I have found `worksheet_change` useful for this but not the ideal answer as an auto refresh doesn't trigger a change event? But does prompt a calculate. Be useful if you had a way round this!"*

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Worksheet_pivottableupdate event to run the macro. You set it up in a similar way to davesexcel answer above.

The connection in question may not be a pivot table but you can use a small and fast pivot table as a trigger.

Set the pivot table to update at the same time as your connection (e.g. set to self refresh every 5 minutes or on workbook open).